# How to export a 2d animation to png files?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to bake a 2d rig animation as a sequence of png files. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Use a renderbuffer and save it to png every frame. (Or manage the viewport to create your own sprite sheet and save a single png)

Answer (score 2):

You cant do this with unity. What is Unity able to do is analyse a png file and extract all sprites on it, but you wont be able to save each one of them in a individual png.

You will have to use other tools to do that. If it's a pixel art you will easily archieve what you are looking for on https://www.piskelapp.com/

If its not, photoshop will do the trick.

Comment: Well, you can do it with Unity but not out of the box, there's a little bit of code involve